# CURL request execution in MIT APP INVENTOR

Tags: http, url, curl, app-inventor, adafruit

I have a curl request which looks like :
curl -F "value=42" -H "X-AIO-Key: **{*io_key*}**" https://io.adafruit.com/api/v2/**{*username*}**/feeds/**(*feed_key*}**/data

I wish to update data from MIT App Invertor to adafruit io feed which I can do using the above mentioned CURL request but I am having problem to get to execute CURL in MIT APP INVENTOR. Can someone guide me how do I convert CURL into URL or in any other format which can be executed in MIT App Inventor. One such format I know is possibly JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the web component? See an example [here](https://puravidaapps.com/dropbox.php) 
And if you really want to take the *curl* path, you could try the [terminal extension](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/using-linux-commands-in-app-inventor-extension/6469/11?u=taifun) by Juan Antonio.